# How to upgrade Ubuntu 10.10?

Tags: 11.04, 10.10, upgrade, updates

I had downloaded Ubuntu 12.10 several times and I tried to install it with USB stick and CD (or DVD) but I experienced several errors. I had a Ubuntu 10.10 DVD, so I have just installed it. But it seems Ubuntu 10.10's update and language support isn't working anymore.

So I've searched and tried everything to upgrade it, but I always run across a error saying 10.10's repositories no longer supported. Even I've just added 12.04's repositories and tried again, but I **again** run across an error saying the same thing.

So how can I upgrade Ubuntu 10.10 to 11.04?

Comment: There is no direct / easy path to upgrade. IMO you are by far better off backing up your data and installing 12.04.